# Why does class object have no attribute

Tags: python

Trying to build a Trie branch. I have looked at my indentation and there are no spaces, just tabs for that. I have also looked at other answers which either aren't reproducible or have no effect. What am I doing wrong? I expect the following outcome:
`*`

`trie.py`

```
class Trie:
    def __int__(self):
        self.root = '*'
```

`main.py`

```
import trie_test


if __name__ == '__main__':
    trie = trie_test.Trie()
    print(f'trie root: {trie.root}')
```

Error

```
line 13, in <module>
    print(f'trie root: {trie.root}')
AttributeError: 'Trie' object has no attribute 'root'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`def __int__` should be `def __init__`.